# adding indicators into a string according to different case

Tags: javascript

I will receive an array of string-like below.
In each string, there may be three signs: `$`,`%`,`*` in the string

For example,
“I would $rather %be $happy, %if working in a chocolate factory”
“It is ok to play tennis”
“Tennis $is a good sport”
“AO is really *good sport”
**However, there may be no signs in it, maybe only one sign in it.**

There are only five cases in string,
*1*. no sign at all,
*2*. having $,% ;
*3*. having only $,
*4* having only %,
*5* having only *

If there is no sign, I don’t need to process it.
Otherwise, I need to process it and add an indicator to the left of the first sign that occurs in the sentence.

For example:
“I would ---dollorAndperSign—-$rather %be $happy, %if working in a chocolate factory”
“Tennis --dollorSign—-$is a good sport”

**This is my idea code.**

So, I need to decide if the string contains any sign. If there is no sign, I don’t need to process it.

```
texts.map((text) => {
  if (text.includes("$") || text.includes("%") || text.includes("*")) {
    //to get the index of signs
    let indexOfdollar, indexOfper, indexOfStar;
    indexOfdollar = text.indexOf("$");
    indexOfper = text.indexOf("%");
    indexOfStar = text.indexOf("*");

    //return a completed process text
  }
});
```

Question:

how do I know which index is the smallest one in order to locate the position of the first sign occurring in the text? Getting the smallest value may not be the correct approach coz there may be the case that I will get -1 from the above code?

Comment: what are the standard indicators which you're expecting in different cases?

Comment: like the example, indicator will be in these formats: ---dollorAndperSign—- , --dollorSign—-  , --starSign—- , --perSign—- : etc....

Comment: Coz there are only five cases in string , 1. no sign at all, 2. having  $,% ; 3. having only $, 4. having only %, 5. having only *

Comment: I think you should put all those cases/indicators in your question, so supporters can have better insights into what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I focussed only on the *"get the smallest index"* part of your question... Since you will be able to do what you want with it after.

You can have the `indexOf()` in an array, filter it to remove the `-1` and then use [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) to get the smallest one.

**Edited** to output an object instead, which includes the first index and some booleans for the presence each char.

```js
const texts = [
  "I would $rather %be $happy, %if working in a chocolate factory",
  "It is ok to play tennis",
  "Tennis $is a good sport",
  "AO is really *good sport"
]

const minIndexes = texts.map((text,i) => {
  //to get the signs
  const hasDollard = text.indexOf("$") >= 0
  const hasPercent = text.indexOf("%") >= 0
  const hasStar = text.indexOf("*") >= 0
  
  //to get the first index
  const indexes = [text.indexOf("$"), text.indexOf("%"), text.indexOf("*")].filter((index) => index >= 0)
  if(!indexes.length){
    return null
  }
  return {
   index: Math.min( ...indexes),
   hasDollard,
   hasPercent,
   hasStar
 }
});

console.log(minIndexes)
```

Comment: Is there a way to also get to know what signs actually in the sentence at the same time?

Comment: Yes... I edited.

Comment: its so smart. i wonder how you think of it, could you tell me please

Comment: lol... I just know how... Can't explain ;)

Comment: damn it, i wonder if I should give up programming. People like you always seems to get the answer so easy, while I took so long even couldnt get it

Comment: Don't get discouraged. It come with time and practice. When you know all methods by heart... I suggest you to try a couple challenges on [codingame](https://www.codingame.com/start) ;)

Comment: So,you think it is just I known too little?

Comment: so finally i deleted my answer. it was not helpful at all.

Comment: @NinaScholz it's really helpful! Sor, didnt I show my appreciation to you? I learnt a lot from your previous answer, and you last answer did answered my question. Then I just immediately show my admire of your intelligent. If this made you misunderstood. I apologize.  Plus, It's just that there is only one answer accepted. Your answer is also really eye opening. Just thanks again!

Comment: @NinaScholz
I just realized that I can make more than one tick. If you want, you may pose it again and I can show my appreciation to you as marking it as accepted. So you can get rewarded as you deserve.

Comment: I just try to recall your ans as I think it still worth to be seen

Answer (score 0):

```js
const texts = [
  "I would $rather %be $happy, %if working in a chocolate factory",
  "It is ok to play tennis",
  "Tennis $is a good sport",
  "AO is really *good sport"
]

texts.forEach(text => {
  let sighs = ["%","$","*"];
  let chr = text.split('').find(t => sighs.find(s => s==t));
  if (!chr)
    return;
    
  text = text.replace(chr, "---some text---" + chr);
  console.log(text);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const data = ['I would $rather %be $happy, %if working in chocolate factory', 'It is ok to play tennis', 'Tennis $is a good sport', 'AO is really *good sport']

const replace = s => { 

    signs = { $: 'dollar', '%': 'per', '*': 'star' },
    characters = Array.from(s, (c,i)=> '$%*'.includes(c)? c:'').join('')
    headText = [...new Set(Array.from(characters))].map(c => signs[c]).join('|') 

    s.replace(/[\$\%\*]/, `--${text}--$&`);
}

const result = data.map(replace)
```